# Does every permutation, which is not an $n$-cycle, commute with some transposition?

Tags: permutations

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2974822/750041) addresses how many permutations $σ∈S_n$ commute with a given transposition $(i \space j)$. What about the other way around, namely: How many transpositions $(i \space j)$ commute with a given permutation $σ∈S_n$? [I know](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3547979/751182) that if $\sigma$ in as $n$-cycle, then this number is zero (no one transpostition commutes with an $n$-cycle). I'm not particularly interested in the exact number, but rather

> if it is nonzero for *every* permutation which is not an $n$-cycle.

Comment: Well, in $S_4$, e.g., $(12)$ commutes with $(34)$, i.e. $(12)(34) = (34)(12).$  And in $S_8$, $(12)$ commutes with $(34), (45), (56), (67), (78)$, et al.

Comment: This question is also a continuation of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547979/does-every-permutation-commute-with-some-transposition).

Comment: Yes, it is. I have made a link to it in the body of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(123)(456)$ does not commute with any transpositions in $S_6$. It suffices to notice that:

$$
(123)(456)(12)=(13)(456)\\
(12)(123)(456)=(23)(456)
$$

$$
(123)(456)(14)=(156423)\\
(14)(123)(456)=(123456)
$$

and any transposition in $S_6$ will either have two elements in common with one of the two 3-cycles or one element in common with each, and so will behave analogously to one of the two above.

In general, a transposition $(ij)$ will commute with a permutation $\sigma$ if and only if one of the following two things is true:

- $i$ and $j$ are fixed points of $\sigma$, or
- the transposition $(ij)$ appears in the cycle structure of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

With $\theta \in S_n$ then $(i\space j)$ commutes with $\theta$ if and only if $\theta'= (i\space j)\theta (i\space j)=\theta$. We can get $\theta'$ "sweeping" $i$ and $j$ from $\theta$.

For example consider $\theta=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)$

Then "sweeping" 1 and 2 we get $\theta'=(1\space 2)\theta(1\space 2)= \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right)$

So  $\theta \in S_n$ commutes with $(i\space j)$ if and only if $\theta(i)=i$ and $\theta(j)=j$

Comment: or if $\theta(i)=j$ and $\theta(j)=i$